# Cannot find "go" binary installed by asdf

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I get the following error after installing Go with `asdf` and trying to open a Go project.

```
Failed to find the "go" binary in either。GOROOT() or PATH(/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin). Check PATH, or Install Go and reload the window.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed this by just restarting VSCode.

Another person also suggest a fix in [this issue](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/971#issuecomment-927666108) which I didn't need to do.

1. Shift + Cmd + P
2. Search for: "open settings" and choose "Open Settings (JSON)"
3. Run `go env` and copy GOROOT value (in my case it's `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.17.1/libexec`).
4. Add new record to settings.json:

```
"go.goroot": "Copied/GOROOT/path",
```

in my case it's:

```
"go.goroot": "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.17.1/libexec"
```

Newer versions of Go/Brew, the path will be different. This is what your settings.json would look like:

```
"go.alternateTools": {
    "go": "/opt/homebrew/bin/go"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above accepted answer will give you error once you have updated your golang to newer version you find respective solution from [here](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/971) or simply edit `settings.json` add below line should work

```
"go.alternateTools": {
    "go": "/opt/homebrew/bin/go"
}
```